# How to make all URL redirect to HTTPS

Tags: 7, redirection, security, .htaccess, ssl

There is already a lot of links displaying videos inside my site (in node content) that are using:

http://example.com/clips/2017/01/11/51706, http://www.example.com/clips/2017/01/11/51706, https://example.com/clips/2017/01/11/51706, https://www.example.com/clips/2017/01/11/51706

So I want to standardize (make it uniform) all the my links to :

https://example.com/clips/2017/01/11/51706, https://www.example.com/clips/2017/01/11/51706

Redirecting the main URL works using .htaccess but the videos in the body of my articles that are **HTTP** are not affected so not displaying (I have a blank space instead )...

How can I make the internals links (the videos in the body of my articles) that are HTTP to redirect to HTTPS too?

**Update**
Videos are included using this embed code:

```
<div class="media_embed" height="300px" width="400px"><iframe allowfullscreen="" class="video-embed" frameborder="0" height="300px" scrolling="no" src="http://example.com/embed/clips/2017/01/11/51706" width="400px"></iframe></div>
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: How exactly do you include your videos? Through th me body field? How are they stored?

Comment: Just to make sure, are your links in your content relative, eg. `/clips/2017/01/11/51706` instead of `http://www.example.com/clips/2017/01/11/51706`

Comment: @schlicki, I have my video in the cloud. I just add and the embed code which is in an iframe. I updated the question with the code.

Comment: @rooby, not all of them... I have a little bit of everything: relative, http, https but the problem is redirecting the http ones.

Comment: Can you add your current .htaccess redirects to the question.

Comment: When setting up a redirect, you do it in the .htaccess file, telling your server to redirect all http links to https. You just need to uncomment the relative code .htaccess. Your links will still display as http, however when the user clicks on them, they will be redirected to https. If you want to have the links themselves be changed, you'll need to either go through and manually edit them, create a script that goes through and edits them, or create an input filter that changes http to https (then clear your cache).

Comment: @rooby, updated question with the redirect

Comment: @Jaypan, I thought it was possible to do that without  a script but i may end up doing it that way and update the DB body filed.